# Control Names Causing my Macro to Crash

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a series of macros in a form that I have created for my field people to use.  When they have completed the document and want to send it on to the appropriate folks, I have created a FINISH Macro.  This basically cleans up the document for them, dropping the file size down to about 50KB from 2MB+
The macro (below) basically does the following:

A.) Delete the control buttons I put on the form for them to use when they are entering their data.  These buttons are;
**Freeze Data** - Converts all formulas in the document to static text
**Save File** - Gives the file a unique name based on the contents of a cell on the document
**FINISH** - Button corresponding to the FINISH macro

B.) Deletes the tab with the drop down data on it.

When I try to use the FINISH button to run the macro, I get a message that says "Cannot run the macro "Assessment Format - 2.xlsm'Button11_Click'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

[Macros in The workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8laV.png)
However, when I pull up the list of macros, it clearly shows the macro *is* in that workbook.

```
Sub Finish()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'
' Finish Macro
' Finish Document For Sending out
'
'
    Sheets("DropDownData").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 10")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 11")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 9")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A6").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind folks, I figured it out.  I had changed the name of the document, but the macro I assigned to the control button was still connecting to the original document's name.
Came to me when I realized I could run the macro from the list of macros in the document, but not from the button itself.